# How to add a click event handler to a wxStaticBitmap component?

Tags: onclick, wxwidgets

I want to add click event handler to a wxStaticBitmap component.

I use the following statement to create a dynamic event handler:

```
Connect(ID_STATICBITMAP1,wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&MyFrame::OnStaticBitmap1Click);
```

In OnStaticBitmap1Click(), I just want include the following function call:

```
wxMessageBox(_T("Hello World"));
```

However, obviously, my code doesn't work. When I click on the static bitmap, nothing happens.
Can anyone tell me why? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A wxBitmapButton issues an wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED event.

A wxStaticBitmap does not.